# Azure Logic Apps - text to xml webservice

Tags: xml, web-services, azure-logic-apps

Folks, I am completely new to Azure and have been tasked to move some of our integration work from BizTalk to Azure Logic apps. This will the first interface and this is the task.

1. Read flat file from blob .
2. For each record in the file except for the header invoke webservice that takes xml request.
3. Record webservice response in sql table.

This is the approach I am taking

1. Convert text to xml using flat file encoding to convert text to xml.
2. Go through each record using foreach and create xml request in the foreach loop
3. Invoke webservice in the foreach loop and save response in sql table.

I understand logic apps work much better with json so can someone help me understand in the steps above
when should I use json instead of xml ? Is there a text to json converter ?
Can I convert each json record to xml request ? Can I convert webservice xml response to json easily ?

Are any of the steps above correct per Azure's ever evolving actions or is there a simpler approach ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a text to json converter?

Not to my knowledge, but you could use [Liquid transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform) or [Inline code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code) (JavaScript) for that purpose.

> Can I convert each json record to xml request?

Yes, the [`xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#xml) function can be used to achieve that. Very useful, though it does have some limitations (no namespaces; the JSON object must have only one root property, which can't be an array; etc.)

> Can I convert webservice xml response to json easily?

The [`json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#json) function does that.

> Are any of the steps above correct or is there a simpler approach?

There could be a simpler approach, but it all depends on the format of your flat file, the XML request schema, XML response schema, etc. - there's no universal approach. E.g. for some scenarios the use of the [`split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#split) function and the [`Compose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action) action could simplify the implementation.